# Google api example not working

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm trying to run the following Google Api example:

```
<:html:>
  <:body:>
    <:div id='content':>
      <:h1:>Events<:/h1:>
      <:ul id='events':><:/ul:>
    <:/div:>
    <:a href='#' id='authorize-button' onclick='handleAuthClick();':>Login<:/a:>

    <:script:>

var clientId = redacted; 
var apiKey = redacted;
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

      function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
  window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
  checkAuth();
}

function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true},
      handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
  if (authResult) {
    authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    makeApiCall();
  } else {
    authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
    authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
   }
}

function handleAuthClick(event) {
  gapi.auth.authorize(
      {client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false},
      handleAuthResult);
  return false;
}
function makeApiCall() {
  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'primary'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      for (var i = 0; i <: resp.items.length; i++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resp.items[i].summary));
        document.getElementById('events').appendChild(li);
      }
    });
  });
}
    <:/script:>
    <:script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad":><:/script:>
  <:/body:>
<:/html:>
```

Whenever I run the file I get two errors:

gapi.client object is null or undefined

window.sessionStorage.length object is null or undefined

For the last error it gives this url as the source:
[https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.nl.4xKjGS6fluU.O/m=client/am=QQ/rt=j/d=1/rs=AItRSTMdnq2AHV2okN-h3tZllkPQibG86w/cb=gapi.loaded_0](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.nl.4xKjGS6fluU.O/m=client/am=QQ/rt=j/d=1/rs=AItRSTMdnq2AHV2okN-h3tZllkPQibG86w/cb=gapi.loaded_0)

I'm running IE8, does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
  window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
  checkAuth();
}
```

You're calling `checkAuth()` twice. Maybe the `setTimeout()` is necessary for a valid response?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the same example (like hello world) from official documentation page [here](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#hiworld)

is declaring to use variables:

```
  // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
  var developerKey = 'xxxxxxxYYYYYYYY-12345678';

  // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console. Replace with your own Client ID.
  var clientId = "1234567890-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.apps.googleusercontent.com"

  // Scope to use to access user's photos.
  var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photos'];
```

but developerKey variable if browser API key is used returns error that API is inaccessible and when creating server key and using it instead everything works fine.